# How to restore an old MySQL database from XAMPP to new location?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I need to restore a database but cannot move the folder across due to permission issues. The folder sits on my old version of XAMPP⁩:

> Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨XAMPP⁩ ▸ ⁨xamppfiles⁩ ▸ ⁨var⁩ ⁩ ▸ ⁨mysql

And the new folder sits here:

```
nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/var/mysql
```

All the folders are locked and I can't get the permissions to change. Is it possible to connect my old database to phpMyAdmin to export the SQL? Or is there a way of getting this folder moved to the locked directory?

Any help would be great, I’ve been researching for hours and cannot find a solution.

Comment: What you are describing as your approach seems overly complex and risky. Can you launch XAMPP? If so it should have phpMyAdmin installed. Just then go into phpMyAdmin and export the database you want to import into a new location and you should be good to go. But to be 100% clear when you point out database directory paths, that is really the worst way to migrate any database. The best is to export the SQL from one database and import it into the other database; that’s how the pros do it.

Comment: HI thanks for your response. So I haven't accessed these old databases for years and not sure how to access phpmyadmin for these old databases. If i launch the software it just points to the new databases. If there is an easy way to switch temporarily to export this 1 database that would be my preferred way?

Comment: Posted a [full answer](https://superuser.com/a/1444161/167207). If you cannot get XAMPP to properly connect to phpMyAdmin, then the next best choice—in my opinion—would be to copy the specific MySQL database directory you want from XAMPP to MAMP and then export it via phpMyAdmin there and away you go!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing as your approach—copying raw database files from the file system—seems overly complex and risky.

Can you launch XAMPP? If so it should have phpMyAdmin installed. Just then go into phpMyAdmin and export the database you want to import into a new location and you should be good to go. But to be 100% clear when you point out raw database directory paths, that is really the worst way to migrate any database in case like this.

The best is to export the SQL from one database and import it into the other database; that’s how the pros do it.

That said, if you cannot launch XAMPP in a way that you can connect to phpMyAdmin, there is another way to deal with this: All of your database files for a specific database will be in a directory with that database name in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles⁩/var/mysql/`. So something like `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles⁩/var/mysql/my_cool_database/` will be there.

Now, install [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) on your Mac. With that done, do not start MAMP—maybe even stop it if it automatically starts up—but just copy the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles⁩/var/mysql/my_cool_database/` directory to the MySQL database directory in MAMP located here: `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/mysql/my_cool_database/`.

Be sure to make a copy; don’t just move the directory. Give yourself a de-facto backup by using a copy instead of the original.,

With that done, start MAMP, go to the welcome page and go to the phpMyAdmin that is built into MAMP.

If everything goes well, your `my_cool_database` should be listed in the phpMyAdmin database list and you can now export that database and import it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for this and yes I was able to get the database listed in the phpmyadmin sidebar with all the wordpress tables listed but when I click on it to export it gives me the error of: No tables found in database. If i then click on the tables in the side panel I have lots of errors relating to: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers. 1 example of these are:

Comment: Warning in ./libraries/classes/Controllers/Table/TableStructureController.php#1382
Illegal string offset 'Data_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Controllers/Table/TableStructureController.php#1278: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
./libraries/classes/Controllers/Table/TableStructureController.php#377: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(

Comment: In the MAMP menu there should be a “Tools” item. There are three items there, “Check MySQL databases”, “Repair MySQL databases” and “Upgrade MySQL database.” I would run those—all of them—and see if it can clear things up. If not, [look here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13178). In the case of MAMP there is no default `my.cnf` so just create one in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf` (it’s just a text file‚ and then add this line: `lower_case_table_names=2`. Save the file, stop MAMP and restart it again and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I did all this, the repairs came with errors ie fullcircle.wp_commentmeta
Error    : Table 'fullcircle.wp_commentmeta' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed based on the database and when I add this comment into the my.cnf and try and restart the MAMP servers it will not turn on the mySQL server

Comment: @Eddie_E1 Wow. Sorry to hear about this. I would recommend starting over again: Stop MAMP, delete the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf` file and then delete `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/mysql/my_cool_database/` again. Now copy over `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles⁩/var/mysql/my_cool_database/` into `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/mysql/my_cool_database/` and then delete these two files in that directory: `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/mysql/ib_logfile0` and `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/mysql/ib_logfile1`. Now start MAMP again and check in phpMyAdmin again.